# ghmm: Number of emission parameters is invalid: State order cannot be determined

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I am trying to extend my Hidden-Markov-Model from 4 internal states and 4 observations to 8 states and 8 observations (currently they have pretty much the same meaning, but I might reduce number of internal states).

But now I am getting the error:

```
The number of 8 emission paramters for state 0 is invalid:
State order can not be determined.
```

I can find the error in the [source code](http://nesl.ee.ucla.edu/fw/han/old_machine_backup/ghmm/ghmmwrapper/ghmm.py), but I do not understand where there should a problem. From a theortical point of view I have always been able to add observations by just adding a new observation and a new emission probability for each state. I never heard of something like an *order* in hidden markov models (except for the order of a markov chain, but we always assume 1 there and it doesn't have anything to do with observations).

Does anyone know what's the problem here and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a matching number of output symbols (in examples called `sigma`) to the number of elements in your emission probabiliy matrix (in the examples called `B`).

I forgot to increment the number of elements in `sigma`.